# How do I subscribe to solution and project events from a VSPackage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage, mpf

I'm developing a language service for Visual Studio through a VSPackage. I need to update my parse data whenever files get added/removed from the solution's projects.

I want to subscribe to solution and project events.

I tried as follows, but none of these events get fired when I add/remove projects to the solution or add/remove items to projects.

```
DTE dte = (DTE)languageService.GetService(typeof(DTE));
if (dte == null)
    return;

((Events2)dte.Events).SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded += SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded;
((Events2)dte.Events).SolutionEvents.ProjectRemoved += SolutionEvents_ProjectRemoved;
((Events2)dte.Events).ProjectItemsEvents.ItemAdded += ProjectItemsEvents_ItemAdded;
((Events2)dte.Events).ProjectItemsEvents.ItemRemoved += ProjectItemsEvents_ItemRemoved;
```

What's the best way to subscribe to these events from a VSPackage?

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively you could use IVsSolutionEvents3, which has much better events

```
[PackageRegistration( UseManagedResourcesOnly = true )]
[InstalledProductRegistration( "#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400 )]
// add these 2 Annotations to execute Initialize() immediately when a project is loaded
[ProvideAutoLoad( VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionHasSingleProject_string )]
[ProvideAutoLoad( VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionHasMultipleProjects_string )]
[Guid( GuidList.XYZ )]
public sealed class UnityProjectUpdateHandlerPackage : Package, IVsSolutionEvents3
{
    private DTE _dte;
    private IVsSolution solution = null;
    private uint _hSolutionEvents = uint.MaxValue;

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine( string.Format( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Entering Initialize() of: {0}", this.ToString() ) );
        base.Initialize();

        this._dte = (DTE) this.GetService( typeof( DTE ) );

        AdviseSolutionEvents();
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        UnadviseSolutionEvents();

        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    private void AdviseSolutionEvents()
    {
        UnadviseSolutionEvents();

        solution = this.GetService( typeof( SVsSolution ) ) as IVsSolution;

        if ( solution != null )
        {
            solution.AdviseSolutionEvents( this, out _hSolutionEvents );
        }
    }

    private void UnadviseSolutionEvents()
    {
        if ( solution != null )
        {
            if ( _hSolutionEvents != uint.MaxValue )
            {
                solution.UnadviseSolutionEvents( _hSolutionEvents );
                _hSolutionEvents = uint.MaxValue;
            }

            solution = null;
        }
    }

    private Project[] GetProjects()
    {
        return _dte.Solution.Projects
            .Cast<Project>()
            .Select( x => ( (VSProject) x.Object ).Project )
            .ToArray();
    }

    public int OnAfterLoadProject( IVsHierarchy pStubHierarchy, IVsHierarchy pRealHierarchy )
    {
        // Do something
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public int OnAfterOpenSolution( object pUnkReserved, int fNewSolution )
    {
        foreach ( var project in GetProjects() )
            ; // Do something

        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public int OnBeforeUnloadProject( IVsHierarchy pRealHierarchy, IVsHierarchy pStubHierarchy )
    {
        // Do something
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public int OnAfterCloseSolution( object pUnkReserved )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnAfterClosingChildren( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnAfterMergeSolution( object pUnkReserved )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnAfterOpenProject( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy, int fAdded )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnAfterOpeningChildren( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnBeforeCloseProject( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy, int fRemoved )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnBeforeClosingChildren( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnBeforeOpeningChildren( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnBeforeCloseSolution( object pUnkReserved )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnQueryCloseProject( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy, int fRemoving, ref int pfCancel )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnQueryCloseSolution( object pUnkReserved, ref int pfCancel )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }

    public int OnQueryUnloadProject( IVsHierarchy pRealHierarchy, ref int pfCancel )
    { return VSConstants.S_OK; }
}
```

Comment: What is `_hSolutionEvents` in `Initialize()`?

Comment: You're right, updated the code! Had another thought on `_hSolutionEvents` which is needed for `UnadviseSolutionEvents` and add the new code, too. It's a shame that there is not much information out there about making plugins for the best DevTool...

Answer (score 11):

DTE Events are a little weird, you need to cache the event source object (SolutionEvents and ProjectItemEvents in your case), so that COM Interop knows to keep them alive.

```
public class MyClass
{
    SolutionEvents solutionEvents; 

    public void ConnectToEvents()
    {
        solutionEvents = ((Events2)dte.Events).SolutionEvents; 
        solutionEvents.ProjectAdded += OnProjectAdded; 
        // Etc 
    }
}
```

More on this @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165650(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Lets focus on `ProjectAdded` event (although described issue is exactly the same for the rest of the events).

The code sample you've shown attempts to register the `SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded` handler for the `ProjectAdded` event. However, the `SolutionEvents` object exposing the event, has lifetime scope limited to the closure of its wrapping method (you haven't shown its signature - let's call it `Connect`). After the control flow had left that scope, local object has already been garbage collected, so its event is never called:

**Broken code:**

```
public class Connector
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        ((Events2)dte.Events).SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded += SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded;
    }
    void SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded() 
    { 
        // callback is dead
    }
}
```

To fix that, you need to assign the `SolutionEvents` object to some variable, whose lifetime spans over the `SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded` handler - e.g. over the entire wrapping class. In the example below, the scope extends over the entire type (let's call it `Connector`), and ensures that the handler is accessible during the lifetime of that type:

**Fixed code:**

```
public class Connector
{
    SolutionEvents _solutionEvents;
    public void Connect()
    {
        _solutionEvents = ((Events2)dte.Events).SolutionEvents; 
        _solutionEvents.ProjectAdded += SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded;
    }
    void SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded() 
    { 
        // callback works
    }
}
```

To be more precise, check this MSDN reference - [Scoping Variables Appropriately in Event Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb646475%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

> A common mistake in programming event handlers is connecting the event
>   handler to an object that has been declared with a scope too limited
>   for the purpose of handling the event. The object must have a life
>   that spans not just over the function that connects the callback
>   method as an event handler of the object, but also over the callback
>   method itself where the event is actually handled. Otherwise, if the
>   object is out of scope and is no longer defined in the callback
>   method, the callback method is not called and the event is not handled
>   as desired.